# How to rotate image with HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an image (more exactly a streamed video) with a selected angle (0, 90, 180, 270).

My code doesn't work, and I suppose I'm not very far from the solution.

Full code is derived from this example for an ESP32-CAM.
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-web-server-camera-home-assistant/

```
/* CSS ============================= */

@media (min-width: 800px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #content {
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        align-items: stretch
    }

    figure img {
        z-index: 0;
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
    }
}

/* HTML ============================= */

    <div class="input-group" id="rotation-group">
        <label for="rotation">Rotation</label>
        <select id="rotation" class="default-action">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">0°</option>
            <option value="90deg">90°</option>
            <option value="180deg">180°</option>
            <option value="-90deg">-90°</option>
        </select>
    </div>

/* JS ============================= */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {


  const view = document.getElementById('stream')
  const viewContainer = document.getElementById('stream-container')

  const startStream = () => {
    view.src = `${streamUrl}/stream`
    show(viewContainer)
    streamButton.innerHTML = 'Stop Stream'
  }

  const stopStream = () => {
    window.stop();
    streamButton.innerHTML = 'Start Stream'
  }


  // Rotation
  var rot_value = document.getElementById('rotation').value

  //FIXME doesn't work
  view:transform.rotation(rot_value)
```

Comment: Try this:transform:rotate(45deg);

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is an example, you can change it into img:
<div id="Ex">
test
</div>
<style>
#Ex {transform:rotate(45deg);background:red;width:50;}
</style>

Comment: When I do a transform:rotate(45deg) in CSS, it works. The problem is to transfert the JS rot_value to the CSS script properly so that the rotation is changed when I select a value (0, 90, 180, -90)

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what's that means. If you want to change the degree, you can using JS to changing the style

Comment: What I meant is this: transform:rotate work with a constant. How do we do this with a variable? We read that variable rotation_value with JS. How do we feed this into transform:rotate in the CSS part?

Comment: If you want to use JS to change its degree, try this: *document.getElementById("Your ID").style.transform = "rotate("+document.getElementById("Input1").value+")";*

Comment: Update, just reworked on this project.
The reply from Han Han (feb 6) works fine, but I need to press F5 (refresh) to apply the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if a streamed video is the same as a normal HTML5 video, but if it is, heres some css to rotate a video with transforms. This also works for any other normal DOM element, so images will work with this too.

```
video{
  -moz-transform:rotate(20deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(20deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(20deg);
  transform:rotate(20deg);
}
```

You can make it happen over a specified amount of time like so:

```
video {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

If you need anything else drop a comment